# Performance difference of query

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

First, our environment is PHP + MYSQL.
We have a tables Articles, it is a table used to save text articles. There are about 15000 records.
We have performance problem on a query:

```
SELECT article_id, article_title, article_status, 
     article_date_time, article_publish_date 
FROM articles 
WHERE article_status IN ('approved') 
   AND (article_publish_date <= now()) 
   AND ((article_expiry_date = '0000-00-00') OR 
       (article_expiry_date <> '0000-00-00' 
        AND article_expiry_date >= now())) 
   AND articles_id IN (1, 2, 3... a list of about 9,000 possible ID's)
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY article_date_time DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

In our test site (db server and web server are on the same machine), if I run the query for the first time, the execute time for the query is about 30 seconds. 
Still in the test site, if I just refresh the page to run the query for the second time, the execute time for the query is about 0.2 second.

If keeps refreshing, the execute time would still be about 0.2 seconds. But if I stop for about 15 minutes, the execute time would be 30 seconds again, and then 0.2 second...

So here comes **QUESTION 1** : What's making the huge difference between the first execution and the second execution? Cache? If it is so, how did it make the difference then?

Still the same query, In our live site (still, db server and web server are on the same machine), the execute time for the query is about 3 seconds. But the time would be about 3 seconds no matter how many times you run the query.

The test db is a backup of the live db, so the db difference should not make such a different result.

So here comes  **QUESTION 2**: Why is the execute time for the live site not 30 seconds nor 0.2 second? And why wouldn't it vary at the second execution?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: mysql OR sql-server?They are not the same

Comment: Is it mysql-server? What DB type is used? InnoDB? 

for cache issues, - check cache params, it is possible, that in production env you have to small query cache size. Also maybe you have some locks in db on production?

Comment: you must have different configuration in each server. Anyway your WHERE clause seems to be wasting time doing some comparisons (?)
where does the possible ids come from?

Comment: If your main concern is performance, I would first look at the SQL itself. List of 9000 ids? You should create a table with those ids, primary key, indexed and will gain speed. Also why you have `article_expiry_date <> '0000-00-00' AND` ? you can just leave that out, it is implied.

Comment: You could go for a range seek if the ids happen to be contigous `WHERE id BETWEEN x and y`

Comment: @Mihai ,@pomaxa, it's mysql. DB Engine for Articles table is MYISAM.

Comment: Why you have a `GROUP BY` clause. It seems useless.

Comment: @trincot, thanks for pointing these out. I haven't really paid attention to them before. Removing them would definitely help to isolate where the problem is. But still, I think they would not make the performance difference, right?

Comment: is `article_id` set up as a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly the `In (... list of 9000 Id ....)`
The first time you execute the query, the SQL Query processor has to read the data from the disk. In the process it is probably storing the data in cache memory.  The second time, the data is still in cache memory, so it is all RAM access.  The `In` clause (because it is converted into 9000 Repetitions of 
   `Or articles_id = id1 Or articles_id = id2 Or articles_id = id3 ...` takes a long time.   (although I'm not entirely sure on why...

What I would recommend (at a minimum, as a test to confirm this)  is that you put those 9000 Ids into a table and rewrite the query to just join on that table.  Then if that test indicates that this is where the problem is, rewrite your query.

I don't know MySQL/Php enough to know if this is possible there. But in SQL server with .Net for example, you can in the client (ADO.Net) code, create a collection of integer or string Id values, and pass that collection to the database in a single SQL or stored procedure parameter, where it will be consumed as if it were a table, (you can refer to t in a SQL join statement for example) You might want to research MySQL and see if this or something similar is possible in PHP/MySQL.  Otherwise, consider creating a delimited list of these 9000 + Ids and passing that to a MySQL stored procedure, and then, inside the SP, parsing it to convert it into a table that you can join to.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be making sense in a way, especially for QUESTION 1. I would give it a try. Will you be able to give me any hints on QUESTION 2 also :)? THanks in advance.

Comment: I will bet the speed-up is because of query caching, not filesystem caching.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent mysql to use the file system caching? I don't want to wait for 15  minutes for every test... "SELECT NO_SQL_CACHE ..."? It does not do work I think.

Comment: I believe you can set the cache size to zero.

Comment: Yes, you can. See updated answer. To write it in the query, it's `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`-- you had the keyword wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the fast repeat-response is that MySQL can cache queries; the query is not just run faster the second time: it is not run at all, since the system detects that it's seen the query and still has the results. To disable query caching for testing, you can [set the server's query cache size to zero](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html). To disable caching for individual queries, add [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) after `SELECT`.

The list of 9000 IDs is the obvious culprit for the slow performance; but where did they come from? If they are hard-coded in the query, you must know what they are in advance. In that case, the faster solution is to modify your table schema and add a column that records whether the ID qualifies. But the right solution really depends on how the IDs are determined.

**Edit:** Since the list of article ids comes from a complicated query, you should combine the two queries in two. The simplest way is to embed the article-id query as a subquery:

```sql
SELECT article_id, article_title, article_status, ...
FROM articles
WHERE ...
    AND article_id IN (SELECT article_id from <subquery conditions>)
```

But the server will be able to optimize your query better if you take the trouble to rewrite it as a real join.

**Other (minor) issues:** The following clause is redundant.

```sql
((article_expiry_date = '0000-00-00') OR 
   (article_expiry_date <> '0000-00-00' 
    AND article_expiry_date >= now()))
```

If the first half is false, the second comparison will *always* be true; hence you should simplify it to

```sql
(article_expiry_date = '0000-00-00' OR article_expiry_date >= now())
```

To see where your program is spending its time, send a hand-crafted query to the server preceded by [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html), and study the results:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT article_id, article_title, article_status,
    ...
```

Comment: These ID's are filtered results from articles tables depending on variable inputs. We get the filtered result first and then explode them into string, and then pass the string to the query above.

Comment: Then you'd definitely improve performance if you can combine the two queries into one: replace the list of IDs with additional conditions on a table join.

Comment: And make sure everything you use a lot is properly indexed.

Comment: I see. Just the logic to get ID's is too complicated and is used in other places. I kind of hoping adding indexes or changing the other parts of the query would improve the performance so that I don't need to change the complicated logic. But it seems now the ID's list is the key point of this..,

Comment: Indexes certainly should help-- you'll also need them if you go the join route; but saving the round-trip on a 9000-row table is going to be significant too. If the code is complicated, I would definitely try to structure it so that the article id query logic is generated by a single function wherever you need it, and embedded into a bigger query as needed. It does mean you'll have to touch the complicated code to refactor it...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of answering the question why it runs with different timings on the two servers, I think it is important to first try to optimise your query.
First of all you need to avoid the large set of literals you use with an `IN` operator.

I would suggest to add another field 
to indicate the result of this `in` operation:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD (
   flag int
);

UPDATE articles
SET   article_flag =
  CASE 
    WHEN article_id IN (1, 2, 3... a list of about 9,000 possible IDs) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END;

COMMIT;
```

And make sure to put an index on `article_date_time` if not already done:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_article_date_time ON articles(article_date_time);
```

Then use this query without `group by` and one redundant condition less:

```
SELECT article_id, article_title, article_status, 
       article_date_time, article_publish_date 
FROM   articles 
WHERE  article_status = 'approved'
       article_flag = 1
   AND article_publish_date <= now()
   AND (   article_expiry_date = '0000-00-00' 
        OR article_expiry_date >= now()
       ) 
ORDER BY article_date_time DESC LIMIT 0,5;
```

I foresee a performance improvement if you do all this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions. I had added the index on article_date_time, but the 2 questions above covered the real improvement of the index. I will give your suggestions a try and keep you posted.